# Command-line program calling another program

Tags: php, terminal, command-line

I have a program that takes a year and a temperature and returns an amount of days a given year under given temperature. For example `getDaysUnderTemp(2021, -10) -> 13.92`
means that in 2021 there were almost 14 days when the temperature was -10 or below.

Now I'm writing a terminal program that can request information from that first program. So such input `> php temps.php --command days-under-temp --year 2021 --temp -10` in PhpStorm terminal prints the same `13.92`. However, if a command is unknown or some of the parameters is missing, it should give an error. For example when terminal gets input `> php temps.php --command days-under-temp --year 2021` (temperature is missing) it should print some error message.

There is a problem with my code where the terminal doesn't print anything when some parameter is missing. I'm not sure why.

My code:

```
require_once __DIR__ . 'path to the first program';

$opts = getopt('c:y:t:', ['command:', 'year:', 'temp:']);
$command = $opts['command'] ?? null;
$year = $opts['year'] ?? null;
$temp = $opts['temp'] ?? null;

if ($command === 'days-under-temp') {
    if (isset($year, $temp)) {
        print getDaysUnderTemp($year, $temp);
    }

} else {showError('command is missing or is unknown');}

function showError(string $message): void {
    fwrite(STDERR, $message . PHP_EOL);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: You are setting any missing values to null. So if your function can handle null values. There will be no errors created.

Comment: I see. But I'm not really sure how to fix that. Still quite new to php. Any tips?

Comment: You would need to write your own checks. Make sure the year valid. 4 digits only. Upper an lower range.  That type of thing on each option. To start off just keep it simple.

Comment: I changed it to ```if ($command === 'days-under-temp' and isset($year, $temp))```. Seems like it helped but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.